# Single word for feelings of helplessness/hopelessness?

Tags: single-word-requests

I wish I had a bigger dictionary in my brain.

I'm looking for a word describing a feeling you get when you're stuck in a place you cannot escape.

It would best describe how reality makes you feel when you watch an inspiring movie, video, or TV show. You wish that you could live that life, but know that reality isn't so kind and there is little hope it will be better.

Discouraged doesn't seem quite the right word:

> deprived of courage or confidence; uncertain how to act or proceed. (MW/TFD)

It could be used in the following sentence:

That person has such an wonderful life; when I think of my own, I feel _____.

A list of possible fitting words would be splendid. The online thesauruses don't seem to be doing me justice.

Comment: Look up synonyms of 'frustrated', 'caged', 'trapped', 'constrained', 'captive', 'unempowered', 'hamstrung', 'paralysed'  ...

Comment: Well, there are terms like "in a funk" which describe the sort of depression one might get, though it's not necessarily tied to discouragement or hopelessness.

Comment: I edited your post to fit single-word requests; if it is not what you are asking, please feel free to roll back.

Comment: "In a funk" doesn't really describe the correct emotion. "Funk" kind of gives the "Oh, shit happens" feeling, but this character I'm trying to describe has an emotion that is more accurately described as hopeless longing. I just want a better word for it. Resigned is a good one that's been mentioned already, but I'm still holding out for a better one.

Comment: Medica, thank you for editing my post for clarification.

Comment: You will notice that the sense of "hopelessness" and that of "longing" move in opposite directions, I can't really conceive of a single word which will carry both. You may need, at minimum, a two-word phrase, ie., "resigned longing". Your thoughts?

Comment: A child kidnapped from a park and left isolated for 24 hours may long for freedom, but still lack hope in that endeavor. I was hoping there would be a word to describe that emotion.
Taking Edwin's advice, I found some words that may have been useful: immured, stymied, and disheartened. Though, I haven't really heard the first two used in context enough to understand their meaning completely.

Comment: I'm new to this site; what do the (TFD/MW) things mean?

Comment: Those are dictionaries: The Free Dictionary and Merriam-Webster, respectively. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In those circumstances, I might feel [wistful](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wistful):

> Full of melancholy longing or *wishful yearning*; characterized by a pensive longing or yearning.<sub>(TFD)</sub>

or [dejected](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dejected):

> Being in low spirits; depressed; cast down in spirits; disheartened <sub>(TFD/MW)</sub>

Consider, also, [melancholy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/melancholy):

> a sad thoughtful state of mind; sadness or depression of the spirits; gloom; *pensive reflection or contemplation*. <sub>(TFD)</sub>

demoralised, disheartened,despairing, desperate, wretched, *forlorn*, pessimistic, defeatist, resigned, etc. It really depends on exactly how you *do* feel.

Comment: I think wistful was the word I was looking for.

Comment: I think I'll lend our newest user an upvote medica. +1 (you owe me one, Ms. Ross)  ;-)

Comment: I don't know what that means, but thanks, I think. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a fitting adjective for the "*hopeless*" part, but "*hopefully*" this will not be where this sequence ends

> **resigned** adjective: having accepted something unpleasant that one cannot do anything about. "my response is a *resigned* shrug of the shoulders" see Google [resigned](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=resigned+definition&gws_rd=ssl)
>
> **forlorn hope** (phrase of *forlorn*) 1. a persistent or desperate hope that is unlikely to be fulfilled. see Google [**forlorn**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=forlorn+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 1):

Words that come to mind are:

*stifled*: suppressed, curbed, or withheld

*disempowered*: make (a person or group) less powerful or confident.

*stagnant*: characterized by lack of development, advancement, or progressive movement

*demoralized*: having lost confidence or hope; disheartened.

(might change to: "when I think of my own, I *am* demoralized.")

*despondent*: in low spirits from loss of hope or courage.

*despair*: the feeling of no longer having any hope

(change from describing *how* he feels to stating *what* he feels)

Comment: That *all* you got, Tim? ;-)

Comment: Hi, Tim, and welcome. Good list! We tend to be slow, rather than quick, to use bolding and lots of space. I reformatted your answer to be more in keeping with the style here. If you object, please do feel free to roll back. Once again, welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The word is *hapless*.

*Hap* is the root word for *happy*.

[hapless, happiness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hapless)

- Hapless means one is lacking hap, "good fortune, luck"; the words happy and happiness also have the root "hap."
  See also related terms for luck.

*Farlex Trivia Dictionary. © 2012 Farlex, Inc. All rights reserved.*

[Thesaurus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hapless):

Adj.    1.  hapless - deserving or inciting pityhapless - deserving or inciting pity; "a hapless victim"; "miserable victims of war"; "the shabby room struck her as extraordinarily pathetic"- Galsworthy; "piteous appeals for help"; "pitiable homeless children"; "a pitiful fate"; "Oh, you poor thing"; "his poor distorted limbs"; "a wretched life"

misfortunate, pathetic, piteous, poor, miserable, pitiable, pitiful, wretched
unfortunate - not favored by fortune; marked or accompanied by or resulting in ill fortune; "an unfortunate turn of events"; "an unfortunate decision"; "unfortunate investments"; "an unfortunate night for all concerned"

*Based on WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. © 2003-2012 Princeton University, Farlex Inc.*

[hapless](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hapless) (ˈhæplɪs)

Definitions
adjective
unfortunate; wretched

Derived Forms
haplessly adverb
haplessness noun

Synonyms
unlucky, unfortunate, cursed, unhappy, miserable, jinxed, luckless, wretched, ill-starred, ill-fated

*www.collinsdictionary.com*